# Reference request for fractional Poincare inequality

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde, sobolev-spaces, parabolic-pde

Suppose we consider in $\mathbb R^n$, then how to show $\Vert f \Vert_{L^{p}} \leq C\Vert \nabla^{s}f \Vert_{L^{q}}^{\alpha}$, where $s>0$ is noninteger and $\alpha \in (0,1)$?

Comment: Can you be more precise: what are $p$ and $q$ and what do you mean by $\nabla^s f$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Such an inequality cannot be true unless $f=0$.** That can be proved by a standard homogeneity argument. Suppose that $\Vert \nabla^sf\Vert_p<\infty$. Replacing $f$ by $tf$, where $t>0$ we have
$$
t\Vert f\Vert_p=\Vert tf\Vert_p\leq C\Vert \nabla^s(tf)\Vert_p^\alpha=t^\alpha
C\Vert \nabla^sf\Vert_p^\alpha,
\quad
\Vert f\Vert_p\leq t^{\alpha-1}
C\Vert \nabla^sf\Vert_p^{\alpha},
$$
Since $\alpha-1<0$, letting $t\to\infty$, the right hand side will converge to $0$ and hence $\Vert f\Vert_p=0$, $f=0$.

Comment: And on the positive side, one can find a dozen of related (and true!) inequalities of similar sort for example in Samko's book [*Hypersingular Integrals and Their Applications*](https://www.crcpress.com/Hypersingular-Integrals-and-Their-Applications/Samko/p/book/9780415272681).

Answer (score 1):

I guess that your question is ill-formulated: you have to respect the homogeneity on both sides of the inequality. Let us say that for $f$ in the Schwartz space you always have
$$
\Vert f\Vert_{W^{t,q}(\mathbb R^n)}\lesssim \Vert \vert D\vert^s f
\Vert_{L^{p}(\mathbb R^n)}\quad\text{(and also}\quad
\Vert f\Vert_{L^{n/(n-1)}(\mathbb R^n)}\lesssim \Vert D f\Vert_{L^{1}(\mathbb R^n)}),
$$
provided
$
\frac{s-t}{n}=\frac{1}{p}-\frac{1}{q},\quad 1<p<q<+\infty.
$
Applying the second inequality above to $f=u^2$, you obtain for $p>1$,
$$
\Vert u\Vert_{L^{2n/(n-1)}(\mathbb R^n)}^2\lesssim \Vert  uD u\Vert_{L^{1}(\mathbb R^n)}\lesssim
\Vert  u\Vert_{L^{p'}(\mathbb R^n)}
\Vert  D u\Vert_{L^{p}(\mathbb R^n)}
\lesssim
\Vert  u\Vert_{L^{p'}(\mathbb R^n)}
\Vert  \vert D\vert u\Vert_{L^{p}(\mathbb R^n)},
$$
so that
$$
\Vert u\Vert_{L^{2n/(n-1)}(\mathbb R^n)}
\lesssim
\Vert  u\Vert_{L^{p'}(\mathbb R^n)}^{1/2}
\Vert  \vert D\vert u\Vert_{L^{p}(\mathbb R^n)}^{1/2},
$$
an inequality resembling yours. Choosing $f= u^\alpha$ leads  to more general interpolation inequalities.